# Плохо работает Emmet

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, emmet

Проблема в emmet появилась ещё месяца два назад и она заключалась в том, что когда я прописывал допустим:

```
span*3
```

То у меня открывалась структура:

```
<span></span><span></span><span></span>
```

Хотя до этой проблемы структура раскрывалась нормально:

```
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
```

Сейчас же появилась ещё одна, проблема что emmet помогает только частично, если я пишу `span` то эммет помогает мне и даёт подсказки, но как только я добавляю `span*3` то подсказки сразу пропадают, и появляются только если нажать ctrl + space. Но мне так вообще не удобно. Я пользуюсь редактором VS Code.

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл решение проблемы только в установке редактора Brackets